# Get mouse/touch position for NGUI event

Tags: unity, ngui

Since I am using NGUI, to capture mouse events I use their methods such as

```
void OnPress (bool isDown) {

}
```

How can I check the mouse/touch position that corresponds to this particular OnPress event?

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you want to do, and what you've already tried?

Comment: @d4Rk: I'm trying to spawn a sprite at the position the player presses with his finger. I have not tried anything because NGUI lacks documentation on how to get the position given a `OnPress()` callback. I am able to do this using Unity's `Input` class, but I want to use NGUI because my whole game is built with NGUI.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `UICamera.currentTouch.pos` or `UICamera.lastTouchPosition` in the `OnPress` method.

These will be set, whenever a touch is active, and should provide the necessary 
information.